# (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com"); does not responding

Tags: java-me

```
    HttpConnection c = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String request = serverUrl; // + "?loc=" + location.getLat() + "," + location.getLng() + "data=" + message.getString();
    try {
        c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
        c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); //default
        is = c.openInputStream(); // transition to connected!
        int ch = 0;
        for (int ccnt = 0; ccnt < 150; ccnt++) { // get the title.
            ch = is.read();
            if (ch == -1) {
                break;
            }
            sb.append((char) ch);
            return sb.toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return null;
```

in the above code -- this line

```
(HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
```

does not respond. what can i do to resolve this?

Comment: Is the app just hanging (waiting) at that line?  How long does it wait?  Does it timeout and throw an exception?  Are you testing this on a device, or a simulator?  Are you sure that device/simulator has good network connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
 HttpConnection c = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String request = serverUrl; // + "?loc=" + location.getLat() + "," + location.getLng() + "data=" + message.getString();
    try {
        c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
        c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); //default
        int status_code=c.getResponseCode();
        if(status_code!=HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
          //Show the  failure message to user
          return;
        }

        //Remaining part is same as your code
```

Answer (score 0):

In lots of phones, and some simulators, you can only open a connection in another thread. that is to say, if you try to connect in main therad  = UI thread it wont work and wont tell you anything. Try simply wrapping your method in a new thread